# Download QR Code as Image format in Generator

Tags: java, android, code-generation, qr-code, zxing

I'm trying to build a QR Code Generator. My problem is when the qr code is done being generated. It only shows in my app. It can be downloaded or be saved as Image format.

Here's my code for the generator:

```
public class GeneratorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText text;
Button gen_btn;
ImageView image;
String text2Qr;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_generator);
    text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    gen_btn = findViewById(R.id.gen_btn);
    image = findViewById(R.id.image);
    gen_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            text2Qr = text.getText().toString().trim();
            MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
            try{
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text2Qr, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);
                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            catch (WriterException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Can somebody fix this? What should I add or change on my codes to get downloadable QR Code as a Image format? Please help me, I really need it for my project.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem please?

Comment: @Cppplus1 my problem is when the QR Code is shown up after i generate, I can't save it as image format or download it. What command should I use to do that and where should I put such command in my code?

Comment: @Cppplus1 can you help me?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem. I only told you to elaborate because it seemed like it would make the question easier to answer for whoever does know how to solve this.